# How can I delete all images in the album on my Sony Xperia S?

Tags: photos, sony-xperia

I synched all my photos with Lightroom, now would like to delete them from my Phone. There is no delete function in the Sony Album (Android Album?) however. How can I get rid of all photos taken?

Comment: Have you tried a file manager, and deleting the images on the file system level?

Comment: I finally deleted them from Windows Explorer. However I wonder that there is not a simple function for this. I use the Phone as a camera and after thhe files are imported in LIghtroom I want to get rid of them on the phone. Looks like a special app s required to delete photos.

Comment: You might want to put your solution into an answer and accept it (the latter at least until a possible better solution might be offered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deleting based on File Extension:**

You may install [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) from Play Store. Open it and enter the commands.

```
find $EXTERNAL_STORAGE $SECONDARY_STORAGE -iname "*.jpg" -exec rm {} \;
```

You may replace `*jpg` with `*png` , `*jpeg` , or other extensions involving picture formats.

Comment: thats a cool idea

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to a computer and find the folder that stores the photo. Then select all with CRTL + A, right-click and select Delete option from pop up menu

Comment: as i said, that is what i did.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple step and there is no need to install any app.

1. Go to album
2. Press and select one picture/video
3. Once you select a picture you will see top right corner option
4. Open it and you will see select all

Select all images including videos and delete it.